# Finding an estimated solution of the equation

Tags: matlab

I have a truncation function defined as:

```
function f = phi_b(x, b)
if b == 0
  f = sign(x);
else
  f = -1 * (x<-b) + 1*(x>b) + (1/b) * x .* ((x>=-b & x<=b));
end;
```

It is used to truncate the observations which in my particular case corresponds to white noise:

```
model = arima('Constant',0,'AR',{0},'Variance',1);
y = simulate(model, 100);
```

The function I need in the end is:

```
 r = @(b) (1/100) * sum((phi_b(y,b)).^2);
```

The problem is in finding the solution of the equation `r(b)==0.1`. Usual procedures like the one below will not work:

```
solve(r(b)==0.1, b)
```

Is there any way to solve such types of equations?

Answer (score 1):

If the result of `r(b)` is a vector, you could invoke the `min` function and see where in this vector the closest value would be to `0.1`.  You can do something like:

```
result = r(b);
[val,index] = min(abs(result - 0.1));
```

`val` will contain how "close" `0.1` is with the best element in the vector that matches this criteria and `index` will tell you where in the `result` vector this element is.  For example, if `val = 0.00001` and `index = 7`, this means that the best value in `result` is `0.00001` away from `0.1`.  Also, index `7` in `result` is where this best element is located.  To see what the actual value is, do `r(7)` or `r(index)`.

Interestingly enough, you can use `val` as a way of measuring the resolution of your data.  In other words, if `val` is very large, this could mean that you need to introduce more values in your vector at a smaller step size.  If `val` is quite small, this could mean that what you originally specified as your `b` vector is adequate enough.  I'm not familiar with the function so I have not considered whether or not there could be **no** solutions to the data you have provided to your `r` function.